# arm7tdmi assembly explanation + crash debugging

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, embedded

I'm currently investigating a crash that happened compiled with gcc 4.2.1 on arm7tdmi architecture (I could use 4.9.3 on demand). I'm using LPC2387 and I'm getting wdog resets. Instead of wdog resets I'm using wdog interrupts, so when it would reset otherwise, it gets into my handler, which saves state and prints a whole memory dumps (64k only). So basically I know the registers before wdog reset and have a stack showing all of the call history.

On the stack I can see loads of references to the end of the function, and I see many instructions as data in the memory region. Which I think will become the reason for the halt and then the consequent wdog interrupt. Any ideas what might be happening?

I guess reasons can be when dereferencing a function pointer, but my function seems to be quite straight forward. It is touching many hardware registers (interrupt, peripheral enable/disable).

Like this:

2015/05/27 04:45:30:  addr: 4000BF2C value:7FE00390 -->this is  "svcvc   0x00e00390" according to gcc 4.2.1 and  ".word   0x7fe00390" according to 4.9.3.

Also at the end of the function I see this in gcc 4.9.3

```
   191d4:       e89d6ff8        ldm     sp, {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, sp, lr}
   191d8:       e12fff1e        bx      lr
   191dc:       7fe00390        .word   0x7fe00390
   191e0:       40000044        .word   0x40000044
   191e4:       00064de5        .word   0x00064de5
   191e8:       00064dfb        .word   0x00064dfb
   191ec:       4000107c        .word   0x4000107c
   191f0:       e0028000        .word   0xe0028000
   191f4:       e01fc000        .word   0xe01fc000
   191f8:       40001084        .word   0x40001084
   191fc:       4000113c        .word   0x4000113c
   19200:       3800b010        .word   0x3800b010
   19204:       40002a78        .word   0x40002a78
   19208:       40002ab4        .word   0x40002ab4
   1920c:       40002aa0        .word   0x40002aa0
   19210:       40001080        .word   0x40001080
   19214:       400001a9        .word   0x400001a9
   19218:       e002c000        .word   0xe002c000
   1921c:       40001134        .word   0x40001134
   19220:       00064e0e        .word   0x00064e0e
```

It used to look like this on gcc 4.2.1:

```
   1953c:       7fe00390        svcvc   0x00e00390
   19540:       40000044        andmi   r0, r0, r4, asr #32
   19544:       0006d74c        andeq   sp, r6, ip, asr #14
   19548:       0006d764        andeq   sp, r6, r4, ror #14
   1954c:       400012d0        ldrmid  r1, [r0], -r0
   19550:       e0028000        and     r8, r2, r0
   19554:       e01fc000        ands    ip, pc, r0
   19558:       40001390        mulmi   r0, r0, r3
   1955c:       40001394        mulmi   r0, r4, r3
   19560:       e002c040        and     ip, r2, r0, asr #32
   19564:       40002e54        andmi   r2, r0, r4, asr lr
   19568:       e002c068        and     ip, r2, r8, rrx
   1956c:       e002c000        and     ip, r2, r0
   19570:       40002e90        mulmi   r0, r0, lr
   19574:       e002c02c        and     ip, r2, ip, lsr #32
   19578:       3fffc000        svccc   0x00ffc000
   1957c:       40002e7c        andmi   r2, r0, ip, ror lr
   19580:       3fffc0a0        svccc   0x00ffc0a0
   19584:       400012d4        ldrmid  r1, [r0], -r4
   19588:       400001a1        andmi   r0, r0, r1, lsr #3
   1958c:       400012d8        ldrmid  r1, [r0], -r8
   19590:       0006d778        andeq   sp, r6, r8, ror r7
```

Can someone explain me what is in the end of the function? what are the .word regions? Why would I see pointers to this area on the stack?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes after the end of the function chunk is *usually* data.

e.g. if I have `void *somePtr = 0xABCDEF12;` then you will typically get an LDR instruction that puts the value into a register and, assuming little-endian operation, you'll see the sequence `12 EF CD AB` in hex.

Comment: How would that end region be organized? So the svcvc instructions I see there under gcc 4.2.1 just happen to be match a pattern, but it is not an instruction but data?

Comment: Yes, they happen to disassemble to those instructions... which if you look at them are completely nonsensical garbage (and R2 with R0, arithmetic shift right by 32 bits and then store into PC? come on...)

If you were to setup your disassembler with the correct base address that the code will actually run from it *should* recognise those locations as data rather than instructions.